# Enable to make a transition from not display to be displayed

Tags: html, css

Goal:
Make a transition from non visibly to visibly when you scroll up.

Problem:
I have retrieved some info that it is not possibly due to syntax 'display'.
Is there another solution in order to achieve the goal?

Jsbin:
https://jsbin.com/nafarabimi/edit?css,js,output

Thank you!

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="top-content" class="palette-1">
      <div id="testtest">
        <img src="https://www.logolynx.com/images/logolynx/1f/1fa1c2a2ea0d69a85215d878f3a0652a.jpeg" width="100px" height="45px" />
      </div>
      <ul id="iconmenu" class="nav-menu">
        <li class="title">Coffee</li>
        <li class="title">Tea</li>
        <li class="title">Milk</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="palette-2">
      content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> c
</html>
```

---

```
body {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.palette-1 {
  background-color: #83B2FF;
}

.palette-2 {
  background-color: #8BF18B;
}

.palette-4 {
  background-color: #FF8650;
}

.palette-5 {
  background-color: #FF555E;
}

#content {
  grid-area: content;
}

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "left-header header right-header" "left-content content right-content" "left-footer footer right-footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1000px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }
  #top-content {
    
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; /* changed this from 50 to bigger height   */
    

    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #content {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }
  #top-content {
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top: 3px solid #425c62;
  }
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }
}
```

---

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction();
};

// get initial pageYOffset value
let originOffset = window.pageYOffset;

function scrollFunction() {

  // current pageYOffset value
  const curOffset = window.pageYOffset;

  if (curOffset - originOffset > 0 && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    // down
    document.getElementById('top-content').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("top-content").style.marginTop = "-50px";

  } else {
    // up
    document.getElementById('top-content').style.display = 'flex'; // change this to flex
    document.getElementById('top-content').style.transition = 'all 0.5s ease'; // change this to flex
    
    document.getElementById("top-content").style.marginTop = "0";
  }
  // change originOffset value every time
  originOffset = window.pageYOffset;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No You cannot transition with `display:none` because you cannot transition from nothing to something. So Instead I have Used The Height of The `Top-content` initially setting it to 0 and adding 50px on scroll because height can be transitioned.

i also removed `document.getElementById("top-content").style.marginTop = "-50px";` you don't really need to do it..

note*:`@media only screen and (min-width: 300px)` i changed it to 300 so we can see the transition as snippets are small by default.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction();
};

// get initial pageYOffset value
let originOffset = window.pageYOffset;

function scrollFunction() {

  // current pageYOffset value
  const curOffset = window.pageYOffset;

  if (curOffset - originOffset > 0 && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    // down
    document.getElementById('top-content').style.height = '0';
  } else {
    // up
    document.getElementById('top-content').style.height = '50px'; // change this to flex
    document.getElementById('top-content').style.transition = 'all 0.5s ease'; // change this to flex


  }
  // change originOffset value every time
  originOffset = window.pageYOffset;
}
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.palette-1 {
  background-color: #83B2FF;
}

.palette-2 {
  background-color: #8BF18B;
}

.palette-4 {
  background-color: #FF8650;
}

.palette-5 {
  background-color: #FF555E;
}

#content {
  grid-area: content;
}

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "left-header header right-header" "left-content content right-content" "left-footer footer right-footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1000px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }
  #top-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    /* changed this from 50 to bigger height   */
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #content {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }
  #top-content {
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top: 3px solid #425c62;
  }
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="top-content" class="palette-1">
      <div id="testtest">
        <img src="https://www.logolynx.com/images/logolynx/1f/1fa1c2a2ea0d69a85215d878f3a0652a.jpeg" width="100px" height="45px" />
      </div>
      <ul id="iconmenu" class="nav-menu">
        <li class="title">Coffee</li>
        <li class="title">Tea</li>
        <li class="title">Milk</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="palette-2">
      content1
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> c
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**display: none** does not support transitions to another type.

Use **opacity: 0** instead, which can transit to **opacity: 1**

Answer (score -2):

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction();
};

// get initial pageYOffset value
let originOffset = window.pageYOffset;

function scrollFunction() {

  // current pageYOffset value
  const curOffset = window.pageYOffset;

  if (curOffset - originOffset > 0 && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    // down
    document.getElementById('top-content2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("top-content").style.marginTop = "-50px";
    
    document.getElementById("top-content").classList.add("is-scrollingUp");
    
  } else {
    // up
    document.getElementById('top-content2').style.display = 'flex'; // change this to flex
    document.getElementById('top-content').style.transition = 'all 0.5s ease'; // change this to flex 
    document.getElementById("top-content").style.marginTop = "0";
    
    document.getElementById("top-content").classList.remove("is-scrollingUp");    
  }
  // change originOffset value every time
  originOffset = window.pageYOffset;
}
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.palette-1 {
  background-color: #83B2FF;
}

.palette-2 {
  background-color: #8BF18B;
}

.palette-4 {
  background-color: #FF8650;
}

.palette-5 {
  background-color: #FF555E;
}

#content {
  grid-area: content;
}

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}


.is-scrollingUp {
    -webkit-transition: border-bottom-color .2s ease,-webkit-transform .2s ease;
    transition: border-bottom-color .2s ease,-webkit-transform .2s ease;
    -o-transition: transform .2s ease,border-bottom-color .2s ease;
    transition: transform .2s ease,border-bottom-color .2s ease;
    transition: transform .2s ease,border-bottom-color .2s ease,-webkit-transform .2s ease
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "left-header header right-header" "left-content content right-content" "left-footer footer right-footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1000px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }
  #top-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    grid-area: header;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #top-content2 {
    height: 50px; /* changed this from 50 to bigger height   */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #content {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }
  #top-content {
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top: 3px solid #425c62;
  }
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="top-content" class="palette-1">
      <div id="top-content2">
        <div id="testtest">
          <img src="https://www.logolynx.com/images/logolynx/1f/1fa1c2a2ea0d69a85215d878f3a0652a.jpeg" width="100px" height="45px" />
        </div>
        <ul id="iconmenu" class="nav-menu">
          <li class="title">Coffee</li>
          <li class="title">Tea</li>
          <li class="title">Milk</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="palette-2">
      content0
      <br /> content1
      <br /> content2
      <br /> content3
      <br /> content4
      <br /> content5
      <br /> content6
      <br /> content7
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> c
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/mimiqebici/edit?html,css,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="top-content" class="palette-1">
      <div id="top-content2">
        <div id="testtest">
          <img src="https://www.logolynx.com/images/logolynx/1f/1fa1c2a2ea0d69a85215d878f3a0652a.jpeg" width="100px" height="45px" />
        </div>
        <ul id="iconmenu" class="nav-menu">
          <li class="title">Coffee</li>
          <li class="title">Tea</li>
          <li class="title">Milk</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="palette-2">
      content0
      <br /> content1
      <br /> content2
      <br /> content3
      <br /> content4
      <br /> content5
      <br /> content6
      <br /> content7
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> c
</html>
```

---

```
body {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.palette-1 {
  background-color: #83B2FF;
}

.palette-2 {
  background-color: #8BF18B;
}

.palette-4 {
  background-color: #FF8650;
}

.palette-5 {
  background-color: #FF555E;
}

#content {
  grid-area: content;
}

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}


.is-scrollingUp {
    -webkit-transition: border-bottom-color .2s ease,-webkit-transform .2s ease;
    transition: border-bottom-color .2s ease,-webkit-transform .2s ease;
    -o-transition: transform .2s ease,border-bottom-color .2s ease;
    transition: transform .2s ease,border-bottom-color .2s ease;
    transition: transform .2s ease,border-bottom-color .2s ease,-webkit-transform .2s ease
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "left-header header right-header" "left-content content right-content" "left-footer footer right-footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1000px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }
  #top-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    grid-area: header;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #top-content2 {
    height: 50px; /* changed this from 50 to bigger height   */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #content {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }
  #top-content {
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top: 3px solid #425c62;
  }
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }
}
```

---

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction();
};

// get initial pageYOffset value
let originOffset = window.pageYOffset;

function scrollFunction() {

  // current pageYOffset value
  const curOffset = window.pageYOffset;

  if (curOffset - originOffset > 0 && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    // down
    document.getElementById('top-content').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("top-content").style.marginTop = "-50px";

  } else {
    // up
    document.getElementById('top-content').style.display = 'flex'; // change this to flex
    document.getElementById('top-content').style.transition = 'all 0.5s ease'; // change this to flex
    
    document.getElementById("top-content").style.marginTop = "0";
  }
  // change originOffset value every time
  originOffset = window.pageYOffset;
}
```